# JQuery - How do I get the value that was set in an input field's value attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an input field `<input value="hello"/>`. How do I get what is in the value attribute in a cross-browser way?  If I do `$input.attr('value')` or `$input.val()`, it returns the current value that the user has typed into the field, rather than the value that is set in the value attribute.

If I do `input.getAttribute('value')`, it returns what I want, but is that cross-browser compatible?

Comment: you can store that value in variable on document.load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157) property:

```
input.defaultValue;

$("whatever").get(0).defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you would use:

```
$('input').attr('value');
```

But the getAttribute() function should be cross browser compatible.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. Once you change the value of the textbox, this function returns the changed value, not the original attribute's value. Only `getAttribute` reads off the *original* `value` attribute.

Comment: In my question I said that I used that, and it returns the current value, rather than what I want, which is the value set in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YUGQz/3/.

It seems that the `value` attribute is updated when you change the text of the textbox (at least when using jQuery), so `.attr('value')` doesn't work properly.

But if you try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YUGQz/4/, you can see that using *pure* JavaScript, you can get the original attribute's value:

```
document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('value');
```

If anyone wants to try this for cross-browser compatibility, that would be nice. Just change the value of the textbox and press the button.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to add a comment to Blender

That works under Firefox, Chrome and Safari but don't work under IE (8). In IE you get the same behavior you have with jQuery. It returns the current value of the text box.